# Cohomology of the adjoint representation of $\mathrm{SL}_2(k)$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, group-cohomology

Let $k$ be a finite field. Do we always have $H^1(\operatorname{PSL}_2(k), k^3) = 0$, where $\operatorname{PSL}_2(k)$ acts on $k^3$ via the adjoint representation (= conjugation action on trace zero matrices)? If not, is there a simple description of the $k$ for which this does or does not happen?

(For $k$ the prime field $\mathbf{F}_p$, with $p \ge 7$, the vanishing of this cohomology is shown in an old paper of mine with Sarah Zerbes, adapting an earlier argument of Flach for $\operatorname{GL}_2(k)$. But this argument fails for small $p$, and it relies on the $p$-Sylow of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbf{F}_p)$ being cyclic, which is false for non-prime fields. So surely there must be a better way.)

Comment: It seems to me $H^1(SL_2(k),k^3)$ is $1$-dimensional at least for $k = \mathbb{F}_2$ and $k = \mathbb{F}_5$. You might find an answer to your question in "Cline, Edward; Parshall, Brian; Scott, Leonard. Cohomology of finite groups of Lie type. I. Inst. Hautes Études Sci. Publ. Math. No. 45 (1975), 169-191." or "Hertzig, David. Cohomology of certain Steinberg groups. Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 75 (1969), 35-36."

Comment: If I understand CPS correctly, they deal with all finite fields of characteristic $\ne 2$ with $q > 5$. In my application the char. 2 case is banned for other reasons anyway, so the problem is *only* the prime fields $\mathbb{F}_3$ and $\mathbb{F}_5$. Now I need to sit down and work out how $k^\times$ acts on $H^1(SL_2(k), \mathrm{ad})$ in these cases...

Comment: I looked up Hertzig's paper but it is exceedingly terse and the notations are not familiar to me. He defines two groups $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ for each root system. Can @testaccount, or some other kind person, explain to me what these are for $A_1$? Presumably one of them is $SL_2(k)$ but it's not clear to me which.

Comment: Looking at Chapter 6 in Steinberg's lecture notes, then $\Gamma$ should be the universal Chevalley group (so $SL_2$ for type $A_1$). And in the case of a finite field $\Gamma = \Delta$. There are indeed no details in the paper by Hertzig, and it seems none appeared later.

Comment: In that case I am puzzled. Herzig seems to be saying that $H^1(SL_2(\mathbb{F}_3), \mathrm{ad}^0) = 0$. But the first line of the proof of Lemma 3.3 in Bell's paper https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(78)90027-3 seems to show that, for any $p$ and any module $M$ of $p$-power order, we have $H^1(SL_2(\mathbf{F}_p), M) = H^1(U, M)^T$ where $U$ and $T$ are the usual unipotent and torus subgroups. Lemma 1.2 of Flach (http://eudml.org/doc/144023) computes $H^1(U, ad^0)$ as a $T$-module and shows that it is 1-dimensional with $diag(t, t^{-1}) \in T$ acting as $t^4$.

Comment: So if $p = 3$ the $T$-action is trivial, which seems to contradict Hertzig's result. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Isn't Lemma 1.2 of Flach talking about the adjoint module of $GL_2$? It is true that $H^1(SL_2(3), \mathfrak{sl}_2) = 0$. But $H^1(SL_2(3), \mathfrak{gl}_2)$ is nontrivial, since $H^1(SL_2(3),k)$ is nontrivial, since $SL_2(3)$ has $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ as a quotient.

Comment: Sure, he computes with the $gl_2$ adjoint and gets a module with two summands, one from $k$ and one from $sl_2$ – both of which are apparently non-trivial when $p = 3$.

Comment: Of course [CPS]

Comment: I think you are not quite reading [CPS] correctly, it applies to (odd) q > 3 and says the dimension is zero unless q = 5 in which case the dimension is 1. The case q = 3 appears in an equivalent form in a rather famous paper of your advisor's advisor's advisor. You can also find an explicit elementary computation for all odd q =/= 5 in the proof of Lemma 2.48 here (https://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Expository/05.DDT/paper.pdf).

Comment: For q = 5, $G = \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{F}_5)$ is the Schur cover of $A_5$ and the $2$-dim reps of $G$ are defined over $\mathbf{Z}_5[\sqrt{5}]$. So the tautological map $G \rightarrow \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{F}_5)$ has a non-trivial deformation to $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{F}_5[x]/x^2)$ giving a corresponding non-trivial class in $H^1(G,\mathrm{ad}^0)$. (Just in case you wanted a complete proof of which groups are non-zero without having to reference [CPS])).

Answer (score 4):

$\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL}\newcommand\Ad{\mathrm{Ad}}\newcommand\triv{\mathrm{triv}}$I believe that if the characteristic of $k$ is 2, then $H^1(\PSL_2(k),k^3)$ is nonzero, while if the characteristic of $k$ is at least 7, then $H^1(\PSL_2(k),k^3)=0$.

I will now write $\Ad$ for the adjoint representation and $\triv$ for the trivial representation. Note that $H^1(PSL_2(k),\Ad) \cong \operatorname{Ext}^1 (\triv,\Ad)$. So we need to know if there is a non-split short exact sequence

$$0\to \Ad \to X \to \triv\to 0.$$

If $k$ has characteristic 2, then we can take the tensor square of the defining representation $X=(k^2)^{\otimes 2}$.

If $k$ has characteristic at least 7, let me sketch my solution. Start with $X$ as above. Let $N$ be the subgroup which is the normaliser of a split torus. Since $\lvert N\rvert$ is coprime to the characteristic of $k$, we can, and do, split this short exact sequence in the category of $N$-modules.

Write $e,h,f$ for the usual basis of $\Ad$ and $v$ for a basis element of $\triv$. I claim that for every $x\in k$, there exist $\alpha,\beta\in k$ such that
$$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
1 & x \\ 0 & 1
\end{smallmatrix}\right)
\cdot v=v+\alpha e,\qquad
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ x  & 1
\end{smallmatrix}\right)
\cdot v=v+\beta f.
$$
To prove this, I pick $t\in \mathbb{F}_p$ with $t^5\neq t$ (hence the assumption on the characteristic) and apply the identity
$$
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
t & 0 \\ 0 & t^{-1}
\end{smallmatrix}\right)
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
1 & x \\ 0 & 1
\end{smallmatrix}\right)
=
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
1 & x \\ 0 & 1
\end{smallmatrix}\right)^{t^2}
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
1 & t \\ 0 & t^{-1}
\end{smallmatrix}\right)
$$
to $v$.

Now the product $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
1 & x \\ 0 & 1
\end{smallmatrix}\right)\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ -x^{-1} & 1
\end{smallmatrix}\right)
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
1 & x \\ 0 & 1
\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ lies in $N$ so must act trivially on $v$. Substituting in the equations above we end up with $\alpha=\beta=0$, which is enough to conclude as these elements generate $\PSL_2(k)$.

Comment: No, I am really using the fact that t lies in the prime field, because the exponent t^2 has to be an integer.

Comment: Ah, I missed that, sorry!

Answer (score 4):

(Too long for a comment.) A Magma computation shows that for $k=\mathbf{F}_p$ with $p$ prime the group $H^1(\operatorname{PSL}_2(k);k^3)$ equals $0$ for $p=3$ and $7\le p\le 17$ while the cohomology group is $1$-dimensional for $p=2$ and $p=5$. I include the code and output below. If you are interested it is simple to convince Magma to get a generating cocycle for $p=5$. Also in this case note that $\operatorname{PSL}_2(5)=\operatorname{Alt}_5$ and the module is the unique simple $3$-dimensional module.

Program:

```
for p in [2,3,5,7,11,13,17] do  
  G:=AdjointChevalleyGroup("A",1,p);  
  M:=GModule(G);  
  X:=CohomologyModule(G,M);  
  print p,Dimension(CohomologyGroup(X,1));  
end for;
```

Output:

```
2 1  
3 0  
5 1  
7 0  
11 0  
13 0  
17 0
```